# Filtering out records from a datetime array in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have an array of dates in string format (year month day):

- 2018-01-01
- 2018-07-01
- 2018-12-25

I also have an array of datetimes (Y-m-d H:i:s)

- 2018-07-01 9:00:00
- 2018-07-01 15:00:00
- 2018-07-02 9:00:00
- 2018-07-02 15:00:00
- 2018-07-04 9:00:00
- 2018-07-04 15:00:00

I need to filter out the records that don't match the date of any of the dates in the first array.
The correct result would be:

- 2018-07-01 9:00:00
- 2018-07-01 15:00:00

Is there a clean way to code that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use strtotime() function and save dates and date times in integers in your array. Than you can perform any kind of filtering on it. For further details can you please show your arrays and clarify what you want to filter from array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter along with in_array, date, and strtotime:

```
<?php

$dates = array("2018-01-01","2018-07-01", "2018-12-25");
$datetimes = array(
    new DateTime('2018-07-01 12:00:00'),
    new DateTime('2018-07-01 18:30:00'),
    new DateTime('2018-07-02 10:00:00'),
    new DateTime('2018-07-02 18:00:00'),
    new DateTime('2018-07-04 11:11:00'),
    new DateTime('2018-07-04 20:11:00')
);

$result = array_filter($datetimes, function ($datetime) use ($dates) {
    return in_array(date("Y-m-d", $datetime->getTimestamp()), $dates);
});

var_dump($result);
```

This produces the following:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-07-01 12:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-07-01 18:30:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
  }
}
```

If you have a lot of data, you might want to flip the dates into a map with the keys being the dates and the values being true so that you can do an isset instead of an in_array which would be faster.

Comment: If $datetimes is the initial array of datetime records I am trying to filter, and $result is the final array of the datetime records I am keeping, and $dates is the array of dates I am using as criteria for filtering the datetime records, what is $datetime?

Comment: When you iterate over the array using array_filter, the function you pass as a parameter gets passed each element of the array in the first argument. That is, $datetime is the element of $datetimes that is being tested, to either match one of the dates in $dates or not.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I can't eliminate the errors in the code with your method:
$dates=array("2018-01-01","2018-07-01", "2018-12-25");
$datetimes=array(new DateTime('2018-07-01 12:00:00'), new DateTime('2018-07-01 18:30:00'), new DateTime('2018-07-02 10:00:00'), new DateTime('2018-07-02 18:00:00'), new DateTime('2018-07-04 11:11:00'), new DateTime('2018-07-04 20:11:00'));
$result = array_filter($datetimes, function ($datetime) {
    return in_array(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($datetime)), $dates);
});

Comment: @JeffSayers The reason it doesn't work is because you are using DateTime objects. From your question, I was assuming you had datetime strings in the format ("Y-m-d H:is"). You should update your question to specify the format.

Comment: @JeffSayers I also had a missing `use ($dates)` before the function. I've updated my answer with the data from your comment. If you run it, you'll see that it works.